# Объясните разницу между mysql.createConnection и mysql.createPool в nodejs

Tags: node.js

Народ объясните плиз разницу между созданием одиночного соединения и пула соединений с базой данных.

1. В чем отличие?
2. Когда и какое лучше использовать?
3. Как фиксить падение пула соединений из-за таймаута mysql?
4. В чем опасность открытия пула соединений, не будет ли из-за него тормозиться работа mysql?

Для одиночных соединений, я использую такую функцию.

```
    User.prototype.create_connection = function(user, database, password, name_connection) {
      var this_=this;
      var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : user,
          password : password,
          database : database,
          multipleStatements: true
      });

      if(name_connection=="x") {
         global.x=connection;
      } else if(name_connection=="xx"){
         global.xx=connection;
      }

      connection.connect(function(err) {              // The server is either down
        if(err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
          console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
          setTimeout(function(){
              this_.create_connection(user, database, password, name_connection);
          }, 1000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
        }
      });

      connection.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('db error', err);
        setTimeout(function(){
              this_.create_connection(user, database, password, name_connection);
        }, 1000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
      });
    }
```

Модуль который использую для работы с базой [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)
Спасибо.

Comment: 3. Никак. если соединение с базой не может быть установлено по таймауту, значит с базой что-то не так. Логика повторных запросов должна быть реализована в приложении, а не в пуле соединений. Чаще всего, если БД не доступна, приложение просто отдает клиентам ошибку и это нормально.

Comment: А еще вам не стоит использовать `global` в Node.js за исключением совсем уж крайних случаев.

Comment: Почему? Мне там удобно хранить соединения с базой. Так как оно  часто отпадает и теряется. Переподключаться же к базе при каждом новом обращении пользователей отнимает примерно 1-2 секунды.

Comment: Я говорю не о переподключении, а о глобальный переменных. Глобальные переменный стоит использовать только в крайнем случае и это справедливо для любого языка. Сходу могу назвать две причины: тестирование и спагетти код.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если в двух словах, пул соединений - это сущность, в обязанности которой входит создание, переиспользование и утилизация соединений.

Пул MySQL соединений, реализованный в модуле `node-mysql` не создает больше соединений, чем этого требует приложение. Если в пуле нет свободных соединений (и лимит соединений еще не достигнут) пул *сам* создает новое соединение и возвращает его клиентскому коду. Если клиентский код больше не нуждается в соединении, он возвращает его обратно в пул. Это позволяет использовать такие соединение повторно.

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    // ...
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    // Соединение извлечено из пула. Обратите внимание, вам не нужно
    // создавать соединение. Пул вернет вам уже существующее свободное соединение
    // или сам создаст новое.
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM data', function() {
        // Соединение больше не нужно. Возвращаем его в пул.
        connection.release();
    });
});
```

При падении соединения (например по таймауту) пул просто утилизирует его. При следующем обращении клиентского кода, это соединение уже не будет использоваться.

Что касается производительности, то при использовании пула соединений, есть небольшой оверхед на мониторинг активности соединений и их утилизацию. В тоже время, возможность переиспользования соединений позволяет сэкономить на подключениях к БД, что является более длительной операцией.

В целом использование пула помогает с одной стороны избавиться от большого количество головной боли с созданием/переиспользованием/утилизацией соединений, а с другой немного увеличить производительность, за счет повторного использования соединений.

Comment: Все равно не пойму. Вот я создал соединение через mysql.createConnection при запуске скрипта и использую его для всех своих запросов в течении следующих скажем 24 часов. Каккая мне выгода тогда от создания пула mysql.createPool с кучей соединений? Правильно ли я понимаю, что если мое одиночное соединение будет использовано в одном запросе, и с это время самое же время какае-то функция попробует тоже его использовать, то возможно будет ошибка и чтобы этого избежать мне нужен пул?

Comment: Пул не создает "кучу" соединений. Он создает ровно столько соединений, сколько требуется клиентскому коду. Если нигде в коде вы не выполняете параллельных запросов, в пуле будет не более одного соединения. И да, если соединение вдруг отвалится по таймауту, для пула это не будет проблемой. При следующем запросе от клиентского кода пул вернет _новое_ соединение.